# Get the avg of 2 numbers in one csv field python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to clean a dataset(csv) in python (pandas)
[image]

In the Projected investment columns I have data that contains 2 numbers. for example 30-35 how can I get the avg of this so that the field contains 32.5

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please include a code sample as code, not as an image.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best is create `float` column, not mixed numeric with strings.

First [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) `missing` to `NaN`s, then [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html), convert to floats and last get `mean`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Projected investment':['missing','30-35','77']})
print (df)
  Projected investment
0              missing
1                30-35
2                   77

df['Projected investment'] = df['Projected investment'].replace('missing', np.nan) \
                                                       .str.split('-', expand=True) \
                                                       .astype(float) \
                                                       .mean(axis=1)
print (df)
   Projected investment
0                   NaN
1                  32.5
2                  77.0

print (df['Projected investment'].dtypes)
float64
```

If need `missing` as string:

```
def parse_number(x): 
    try: 
        return np.mean(np.array(str(x).split('-')).astype(float))
    except ValueError: 
        return x 

df['Projected investment'] = df['Projected investment'].map(parse_number) 
print (df)
  Projected investment
0              missing
1                 32.5
2                   77

print (df['Projected investment'].apply(type))
0              <class 'str'>
1    <class 'numpy.float64'>
2    <class 'numpy.float64'>
Name: Projected investment, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks I fixed it doing something like this.

Comment: 'code' def parse_number(x):
    try:
        numbers = str(x).split('-')
        if len(numbers) == 1:
            return float(numbers[0])

        return (float(numbers[0]) + float(numbers[1])) / 2
    except ValueError:
        return x
    

df['Projected investment'] = df['Projected investment'].map(lambda x: parse_number(x))
df 'code'

Answer (score 0):

This will work as long as you are not having `NaN` or `missing values` in that column. You need to take care of that first

```
df['Projected Investment'] = df['Projected Investment'].apply(lambda x : np.mean(map(int, x.split('-'))))
```

Comment: I tried something like this but I want to keep the missing values in my dataset.

Comment: Then you can pass a function in the `apply()` method that handles all those cases

Comment: How can I achive something like this? I've tried some things multiple times.

Comment: Can you just tell me the the different type of values that are in that column? For that just do this `df['Projected Investmet'].value_counts()`

Comment: If there is text in the column than it should not calculate the avg.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
string_of_nums = "30-35"
nums = string_of_nums.split("-")
nums=[int(num) for num in nums]
rest=nums[1]%nums[0]
avg = str(nums[0])[:-1] + str(rest/2)
print(avg)
#>>>32.5(as string)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df['Projected Investment'].apply(lambda x: x if x == 'Missing' else np.mean([int(i) for i in x.split('-')]))
```